# Prove for $Pr[A] - Pr[B] \leq Pr[A \setminus B]$

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I have events $A$ and $B$

I want to prove that for $Pr[A] - Pr[B] \leq Pr[A \setminus B]$.

I need help getting started. Are there any axioms of probability I could use to rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax: 
$p(X) \equiv $ probability of event $X$ occurring 
$(XY) \equiv $ the *event* that events $X$ and $Y$ both occur 
$(\neg X) \equiv $ the *event* that event $X$ does not occur.

Clearly $(B)$ can be partitioned into two mutually exclusive events:
$[B(\neg A)]$ and $(BA).$

Thus, $p(B) = p[B(\neg A)] + p(BA).$

Similarly, $p(A) = p[A(\neg B)] + p(BA).$

Therefore:
$p(A) - p(B) = p(A) - \{p[B(\neg A)] + p(BA)\} \leq p(A) - p[BA] = p[A(\neg B)].$

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I would start with noticing that $A\cup B = (A\cap B^{c})\cup B$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
(A\cap B^{c})\cup B = (A\cup B)\cap(B\cup B^{c}) = (A\cup B)\cap \Omega = A\cup B
\end{align*}
where $\Omega$ is the sample space.

Moreover, we do also have that $A\subseteq A\cup B$. Since $A\cap B^{c}$ and $B$ are disjoint, the following result holds due to the monotonicity of the probability measure as well as the finite additivity property:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(A\cup B) & = \mathbb{P}((A\cap B^{c})\cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(B) \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}) 
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start with expressing $A$ and $B$ as unions of disjoint sets. $$A=(A\smallsetminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\\ B =  (B\smallsetminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$$Now the additive property of probability can be applied.